# No private key in SSL Certificate for IIS 6.0

Tags: ssl, iis-6, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

We use IIS 6.0 (Win2003 SP2) at work and needed to renew our SSL certificate.
I created a certificate request by using openssl. Therefor I'd created a 2048 bit key with openssl first. I did not use that certreq.txt request file, since that produced format errors at the website of our used CA.
That request has been accepted meanwhile and I got a .pem file from our organization's CA. So far so good. I even was able to import the certificate. But unfortunately the private key is missing now. I think, windows (or IIS) just doesn't know, where to look for it. The private key of course lives in a *.key file, that I used for creating the request.

But how may I integrate the key into the certificate or make Windows/IIS using it?

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: Sorry, next time I will post such matters directly to server fault. It just did not come to my mind that moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to build a PKCS#12 file using OpenSSL using:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey file.key -out cert.p12
```

Then, using the `.p12` file, import both the cert and its private key at the same time.

More info on openssl https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html

Comment: You can download OpenSSL for windows here: https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your running Windows Server take advantage of DigiCert's free utility (http://www.digicert.com/util).

You can create the CSR from OpenSSL if you plan to import it back to OpenSSL and were using Apache.

Otherwise you'll make the CSR request from IIS or running DigiCert Utility and clicking 'Create CSR' option. Once you have the new CSR, submit it to your CA in order to have them issue a new cert that will match the proper private key in IIS.

Once you receive the new cert file, use the 'Import' function on the utility to load the cert file on your local MMC.

Final step is binding the SSL cert to the site's port 443 connection in the IIS console.

If you happen to need the private key, you can use the 'Export' function to create a .key file or a PFX file which includes both your domain certificate and the private key.

Some firewall devices require a PKCS#12 file over the PFX. If so, rename file extension from .pfx to .p12

Comment: The question was: *"how may I integrate the key into the certificate or make Windows/IIS using it?"*. Bruno gave him that with the PFX/P12 commands. The info on DigiCert's free utility should probably be a comment.  Most of your other instructions, like binding to port 443, are completely off-topic. We call these "me too" answers.  Also see [What is a “protected” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764)